# Trying to write a formalization for an optimization problem

Tags: optimization

```
Write the optimization problem that allows you to find the minimal distance using the Euclidian
norm, between a polyhedron {x ∈ R^n : Ax ≤ b} and a hypersphere of center in $x_{0}$ and radius δ.
```

It can be formulated as follows:

Minimize:
$ d = \| x- x_{0} \|_2 $

Subject to:

$Ax ≤ b$ (some unknown restriction given for the polyhedron i think, the problem doesn't really say anything more)

$\|x - x_{0}\|_{2} >= δ$ (assuming the polyhedron doesn't go inside the hypersphere)

where:

x is a vector of length n representing the coordinates of a point on the polyhedron.

A is a matrix of size m × n representing the constraints on the polyhedron.

b is a vector of length m representing the upper bounds of the constraints.

x₀ is the center of the hypersphere.

δ is the radius of the hypersphere.

$\|.\|_{2}$ denotes the Euclidean norm, which calculates the distance between two points in n-dimensional space.
The objective function aims to minimize the Euclidean distance between the point x on the polyhedron and the center x₀ of the hypersphere.

How would you guys solve this problem?